# Vim: Autocommand for a specific file type that has no extension in the name?

Tags: vim

```
autocommand BufEnter,TextChanged,InsertLeave *.sh Neomake
```

I am trying to achieve the effect of the above's command for shellscripts with no extension.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create [buffer-local autocommands](https://vimhelp.org/autocmd.txt.html#autocmd-buffer-local) for a buffer when it has its filetype set to one of the Shell filetypes (such as `sh` or `bash`.)

For example:

```
autocmd FileType sh,bash autocmd BufEnter,TextChanged,InsertLeave <buffer> Neomake
```

You can also use a [filetype plug-in](https://vimhelp.org/usr_43.txt.html#filetype-plugin), adding the following to a file named `~/.vim/ftplugin/bash.vim` (assuming your shell scripts have `'filetype'` set to `bash`):

```
autocmd BufEnter,TextChanged,InsertLeave <buffer> Neomake
```

Comment: Didn't know you can chain autcommands like that!  
Thanks for the snippet.  
Works like a charm.

Answer (score 2):

```
:help autocommand
```

displays a bunch of options, including `autocmd-patterns`.

```
:help autocmd-patterns
```

says this:

> The pattern is interpreted like mostly used in file names:
> *   matches any sequence of characters; Unusual: includes path
> separators
> ?   matches any single character
> ?  matches a '?'
> .   matches a '.'
> ~   matches a '~'
> ,   separates patterns
> ,  matches a ','
> { } like ( ) in a |pattern|
> ,   inside { }: like | in a |pattern|
> }  literal }
> {  literal {
> \{n,m}  like {n,m} in a |pattern|
> \   special meaning like in a |pattern|
> [ch]    matches 'c' or 'h'
> [^ch]   match any character but 'c' and 'h'
> ...
> It is possible to use |pattern| items, but they may not work as expected,
> because of the translation done for the above.

Thus, if we want to match something that doesn't contain a `.<some-suffix>`, we can hack around with something like

```
autocommand BufEnter,TextChanged,InsertLeave *[^.]\\\{4\} Neomake
```

This would match any filename that is at least 4 (maybe 5, depending on if `*` matches the empty string) digits long and does not have a `\..{0,3}` suffix (e.g., `.txt` or the like). If you have suffixes that are longer, you would have to increase your number, which in turn will increase the minimum length of the non-suffixed filenames that it will match. This is an ugly hack, but I do not believe there is a better way.

Comment: Note: for neovim, the document is located at `autocmd-pattern` (without the trailing `s`).